# Edit rejected as conflicted with a subsequent edit

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

As a beginner I usually answer questions very rarely as I think my knowledge not sufficient yet. So I read questions and answers as much as I can and edit questions to correct spelling and formatting to make it easy to read. One of my recent edits rejected by the [Community♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community) and the reason was,

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit

Will it really be counted as a rejected edit?

Comment: Writing a few high-quality questions will get you some rep too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is counted as a rejected edit.  A few rejects are okay, they happen.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly you will get that message when your suggestion failed to improve a severe issue or several small ones so that a reviewer decided to start the whole edit afresh. That is the reason why this *reject* counts.

Make sure to review the edit history of the post. In the comment you will likely find an explanation about what was missing.